# Prove the following statement for given vector space condition

Tags: vector-spaces

It is given that $A, B ⊆ X$ (where $X$ is finite dimensional vector space). Also I know that $A$ and $B$ is mutually exclusive.

Question: Given $Y ⊆ X$, is the below statement true?

$$(Y ∩ A) \oplus (Y ∩ B) = Y ∩ (A \oplus B)$$

Attempt: I tried to use distributivity, but was not sure what to do with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are $A,B,Y$ linear subspaces? $A \cap B = 0$?

Comment: Yep, that one is unclear. If they are subspaces, they can't be "mutually exclusive". If they are just in direct sum, you can try to use definition of direct sum.

Comment: @dcolazin, your definition is correct, and intersection of A and B is 0 as well.

Comment: @dcolazin  Thanks all of you for looking into this. This is on my mock midterm and prof said his midterm is very similar to these.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X=\Bbb R^2,\ A=\mathrm{span}(e_1),\ B=\mathrm{span}(e_2)$ and $Y=\mathrm{span}(e_1+e_2)$, where $e_1,e_2$ is the standard basis.

Comment: Hi, I was told to come up with a proof that applies to any vector spaces. To give more info, A∩B=0 (apparently that is what the instructor tried to come up for the mock midterm paper.) Thanks again!

Comment: You can't have a proof since the statement is not true. This counterexample actually generalizes to arbitrary linear independent $e_1,e_2$ in an arbitrary vector space.

Comment: Hi. first of all, thanks for your response. It is just that I saw other comments that A∩B=0 needs to be clarified. Does above example still work under those condition? thanks again!

Comment: Is it possible to give more in-depth explanation, I want to know this before I take an exam tomorrow.

Comment: Please verify all yourself: these are subspaces, $A\cap B=\{0\}$, what would you get for $A\oplus B$, for $Y\cap A$ and $Y\cap B$? Can you draw them on the Cartesian plane?

Comment: Hi once again. thanks for your help. I know that A⊕B = A + B as A∩B={0}. But not sure about Y∩A and Y∩B. Also I get that A + B is not equal to Y in your example, because dimension is different.

Comment: Which vectors are in $A+B$? What is $(A+B)\cap Y$? Have you drawn it? $X$ is the plane, $A, B, Y$ are lines through the origin. Do you see which lines?